# What happens after EntityManager.persist()

Tags: java, jpa, java-ee-6, glassfish-3

The EntityManger is injected with `@PersistenceContext` annotation. This is a method from my "DAO/Repository" class which is not annotated. This class is injected into the EJB's that needs to get data from/to the database.

Until now I thought that after the persist method below is finished the persistencecontext is flushed and the data is stored to the database but from what happening in my app I start to doubt that. I have made the datasource and connection pool in Glassfish so I am using container managed transactions as far I know, however I do not use any transaction annotations.

Could somebody throw some light over it for me?

```
public void persist(QuestionFeedback questionFeedback) {
    questionFeedback.setCreated(new Date());
    entityManager.persist(questionFeedback);
}
```

Using Glassfish 3, Java EE6 compatiblity

Answer (score 5):

The `persist` method makes the entity persistent, but doesn't yet write the change to the database. This normally happens when the transaction commits (the provider is free to optimize this, it could happen earlier).

With `flush` you can force the write to happen earlier, but it will still be visible only to code that participates in the current transaction. To make the write permanent (visible to all external code), the transaction still needs to be committed.

Without any explicit annotations, your EJB bean will be transactional by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use any transaction annotations the default will be transactions being required. Thus your DAO will run in a transaction and the persistence context will no later be flushed than when the transaction is committed.

From the JavaDoc on `TransactionAttribute`:

> If the TransactionAttribute annotation is not specified, and the bean uses container managed transaction demarcation, the semantics of the REQUIRED transaction attribute are assumed.

From the JavaDoc on `FlushModeType`:

> When queries are executed within a transaction, if FlushModeType.AUTO is set on the Query or TypedQuery object, or if the flush mode setting for the persistence context is AUTO (the default) and a flush mode setting has not been specified for the Query or TypedQuery object, the persistence provider is responsible for ensuring that all updates to the state of all entities in the persistence context which could potentially affect the result of the query are visible to the processing of the query.

This means that the persistence context might be flushed earlier, if you use a query whose result might be influenced by that flush.

Answer (score 0):

Because EntityManager is injected via @PersistenceContext annotation, you are for sure using container managed transactions.

Anyway, your assumption that persist causes transaction commit is wrong. Change performed via persist is made to the database in commit. Documentation of EntityManager says that "new instance becomes both managed and persistent by invoking persist". In this context "becomes persist" does not mean entity is persisted to the database on that moment. On the moment when persist is called, entity is persisted in the terms of PersistenceContext. It is then later on  persisted to the database latest when transaction commits.

Because you are not using any @TransactionAttribute annotations for your methods, default will apply. Default is TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED. This will cause container to create transaction when first business method is called and propagate this on to other methods. Your transaction will commit when the call to the first business method is completed. Then your changes are in database (if no rollback was performed).

Comment: So what you are saying is that business method opens and closes the transaction (the one invoking the persist method above in my code), and after that the transaction is commited? Or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: Yes, if the client of method that invokes persist method does not have transaction context. Then in your case container have to keep care about begin and commit of transaction in the begin and end of the method. If the client have existing transaction then your method joins to that one, and commit takes place somewhere up in client. It does not matter how many layer of these method calls without defined transaction attribute there is, logic stays same: transaction is started and committed in the first one.